# Deleting rows in dataset

Tags: r

I have some corrupted data in my Panel Dataset - for some groups (gid) and time (t) I have more than one observation. All observations have the variable (quantity) - I want R to exclude the observation with the lowest number in quantity.

My current solution has been this, but with this I do not control which of two identical observations that R will exclude...

```
IMS <- subset(IMS, !duplicated(data.frame(t,gid)))
```

Example:

```
Product    Strength    Pack_size    y        t    Quantity    gid
Ibumetin    600MG        100      5.9183     1      10226    2613
Ibumetin    600MG        100      25.3500    1        100    2613
```

In the example the observation to be excluded is the one with 100 in quantity, since 10226>100.

I will be gratefull for the help you can provide,

Henrik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pretty easy way to do this using the ever-useful 'plyr' package.

**Setup**: I need a little trial data to make this work.  Here is what I used:

```
IMS <- read.table(text="
Product    Strength    Pack_size    y        t    Quantity    gid
Ibumetin    600MG        100      5.9183     1      10226    2613
Ibumetin    600MG        100      25.3500    1        100    2613
Simvastatin  30MG         90      14.1630    1       1036    2614
Simvastatin  30MG         90      12.3345    1       2102    2614
", header=TRUE)
```

**Step 1**: Figure out what the [Quantity] maximum is for each set of [gid]-[t] pairs.

```
library(plyr)
temp_IMS <- ddply(IMS, .(gid,t), mutate, Quantity_max=max(Quantity))

#       Product Strength Pack_size       y t Quantity  gid Quantity_max
# 1    Ibumetin    600MG       100  5.9183 1    10226 2613        10226
# 2    Ibumetin    600MG       100 25.3500 1      100 2613        10226
# 3 Simvastatin     30MG        90 14.1630 1     1036 2614         2102
# 4 Simvastatin     30MG        90 12.3345 1     2102 2614         2102
```

We use the 'dd' variant of 'ply' here, since we are expecting a data frame for input and output (d-d-ply).  We're not doing anything special; we're just adding a new column named [Quantity_max] that is calculated by taking the `max()` of the [Quantity] values that share the same [gid] and [t] pair `.(gid,t)`.  The 'mutate' function is what preserves the rest of the data frame and keeps us from having to do a silly little dance to make this work.

**Step 2**: Select the rows that have the same [Quantity] and [Quantity_max].

```
IMS_filtered <- IMS[temp_IMS$Quantity == temp_IMS$Quantity_max,]

#       Product Strength Pack_size       y t Quantity  gid
# 1    Ibumetin    600MG       100  5.9183 1    10226 2613
# 4 Simvastatin     30MG        90 12.3345 1     2102 2614
```

What we've done is to filter the original data frame based on the temporary data frame created with 'plyr'.

**Step 3 (optional)**: If there is a possibility that multiple rows have the same quantity value, then you'll need to find some way of choosing which row you want to use.  If the rows are absolutely identical, then you have a simple solution:

```
IMS_filtered <- unique(IMS_filtered)
```

If, however, you have varying [y] values, you'll need to do something else, like filtering based on duplicated matches while only considering certain columns.  For instance, if I don't care which value is selected as long as the [gid] and [t] pairs are the same, then I can search for duplicates with a simple search, like so:

```
IMS_filtered <- IMS_filtered[!duplicated(IMS_filtered[,c("gid","t")]),]
```

This chooses the first occurrence of a [gid]-[t] pair by saying to select rows that are NOT duplicated.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to reorder the data so that the largest quantities are listed first, and then using the method you provided:

```
subset(IMS[order(-IMS$Quantity),],!duplicated(data.frame(t,gid)))
      Product Strength Pack_size       y t Quantity  gid
1    Ibumetin    600MG       100  5.9183 1    10226 2613
4 Simvastatin     30MG        90 12.3345 1     2102 2614
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct approach from a computer-science perspective.  Ordering data and applying an arbitrary method is far faster (in CPU cycles) than using an approach that mirrors the logic of the problem.  If you immediately understood @James' answer above, I definitely recommend James' solution over the logically-mirrored solution I posted.

Answer (score 1):

you could use unique(df) to return unique rows